# How can I clone project from gerrit container in GCP?

Tags: git, docker, google-cloud-platform, gerrit

I can't clone a project from docker gerrit because of unresolved host.

Gerrit was started in container like that:

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 gerritcodereview/gerrit
```

And when I try to clone project I get such link:
[git broken link screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZQ6x.png)

How can I clone a project without error message:

```
Could not resolve host: d95076061
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname that is being shown in the download url is the hostname of the docker container. Please try to pass the name of your docker host to the container to your gerrit container.

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:2941 -e CANONICAL_WEB_URL='http://gerrit.myhost.org' gerritcodereview/gerrit
```